# pandas read_csv fails to parse timestamps because the separator is a colon

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset, a 200MB txt file where the data is separated with colons, which means that `read_csv` fails when trying to parse the timestamp (and so it should).

Is there anyway I can ensure that pandas can correctly parse the timestamps without me cleaning/manipulating the data?

Here is an example of the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from io import StringIO

to_dt = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

ss = """first_name:date_registered
Philip:9/13/2020 12:03:05 AM"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(ss), sep=":", parse_dates=["date_registered"], date_parser=to_dt)

print(df)
```

```
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(ss), sep=":", parse_dates=["date_registered"], date_parser=to_dt)
  File "/home/mark/uk/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 610, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/mark/uk/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 468, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "/home/mark/uk/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1057, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/home/mark/uk/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2103, in read
    values = self._maybe_parse_dates(values, i, try_parse_dates=True)
  File "/home/mark/uk/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2167, in _maybe_parse_dates
    if try_parse_dates and self._should_parse_dates(index):
  File "/home/mark/uk/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1439, in _should_parse_dates
    j = self.index_col[i]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The issue revolves around the fact that `sep=":"` and that timestamps contain colons (if I was to change `ss` to be delimited/separated by commas instead)

```
ss = """first_name,date_registered
Philip,9/13/2020 12:03:05 AM"""
```

and remove `sep=":"` from `read_csv` the issue goes away, but as mentioned, this isn't feasible due to the size of the dataset.

**Edit**:
An example of one row is

> 12345:888888:Tom:Corn:builder:United Kingdom:London:four years:Travis:9/10/2017 12:00:00 AM::

Comment: Please note in reality the data is actually 11 columns etc and more complex this is just sample data to show the issue.

Comment: Do you have to read the data with pandas? You can read it with standard libraries and then convert to pandas in a reasonable time.

Comment: @OrkunBerkYuzbasioglu I don't have to read the data with pandas. But I would prefer it, I believe there must be a way to overcome this issue with pandas directly and surely im not the first one with this issue. Also, given the size of the file, I did get out of memory issues when trying to make a list of the data when using standard libraries etc. I would consider an answer in the way you suggested but it would be more of a last resort. `without me cleaning/manipulating the data?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sep` argument supports regex. In this case

```
sep = "(?<=\D):"
```

would work well. This pattern matched the colons that do not have a digit behind them. You need to find a good pattern to separate values or just post more detail about your dataset.

**UPDATE:**

With the new example given I think excluding colons in time format will work. But again it depends on other rows of the dataset.

```
sep = ":(?!\d{,2}:\d{,2} [AP]M)(?!\d{,2} [AP]M)"
```

This pattern will match all colons but those that have time format in front. The time format in my pattern is
*(0 to 2 digits):(0 to 2 digits):(0 to 2 digits) AM or PM*

Comment: I've given an example of one row of the dataset to make it clearer, apologies that it wasn't provided earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest loop over file line by line and replace first N occurrences and last M occurrences of the colon with a comma in each row. N and M would depend on the structure of your file. After this, you will be able to use `pd.read_csv()` as usual with comma as separator.